# Restler specify minimum value of array elements

Tags: restler

If I put this in my PhpDoc comment:

```
* @param array $children The SQL idents of the children to add to the parent. {@type int} {@min 1}
```

Then Restler takes that to mean it's an array of integers with at least one array element.  Is there a way to ALSO say that the minimum values of the integers in the array is 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restler does not support specifying the minimum and maximum value of the integers in an array. You need to handle it inside the api method